# Adobe AIR Keyboard Hook

Tags: keyboard-shortcuts, air, flex3, keyboard-hook

I'm trying to add a feature to my AIR app that can listen for (configurable) global keyboard events even when the app is minimized. Ex: CTRL-ALT-SHIFT-F12 to grab a screenshot.

I can't find any way to register a keyboard hook, and listening for keyboard events only captures them when the app has focus. Suggestions?

Answer (score 2):

I don't think that Adobe Air programs can process keypress events unless the application is in focus.

http://forums.adobe.com/thread/420446

Even [this](http://www.adobe.com/cfusion/communityengine/index.cfm?event=showdetails&productId=2&postId=304) question regarding a Global handler for keypresses states that the application must be in focus.

Answer (score 1):

Try hooking onto the stage's KeyboardEvent:

```
stage.addEventListener(KeyboardEvent.KEY_DOWN,KeyHandler);  

function KeyHandler(e:KeyboardEvent){
    trace ("Key Code: " + e.keyCode);  
    trace ("Control? " + e.ctrlKey);  
    trace ("Shift? " + e.shiftKey);  
    trace ("Alt? " + e.altKey);  
}
```

Comment: That only works when the app has focus, what about when it doesn't?

Answer (score 1):

With NativeProcess, you could write an external app pretty easily to listen for global keyboard events and send them back to your AIR app. I might be going down this path now...

Answer (score 0):

I'm testing my Air application in Flash CS5 and I need to disable keyboard shortcuts so I can test my own shortcuts. I can get ctrl-F to work, but ctrl-C will not.

I notice that my keyboard shortcuts WILL work if it's a standard AS3 file that I'm testing.

Answer (score 0):

One method I use is to monitor the clipboard in the AIR app, that only allows you to react based on copied data, but it's at least sort of a way to listen for input when the app does not have focus.