# Show Go button android keyboard AIR AS3 Flash CC

Tags: android, actionscript-3, flash, air, keyboard

I have my Android AIR app almost ready, I'm using FlashCC, I am building a chat app, so there is an input text component on the stage and works fine, but I can't figure a way to show the "Done" or "Go" button on the keyboard to send a message, similar to the one shown on other apps like whatsapp, etc...

any ideas? I've searched on google for answers or docs on this but no luck.

Thanks!!

Comment: just make a button 'send/go' as you made the text input

Comment: I did, but I want the keyboard to have the option too so the user can type and send within the keyboard

Comment: http://help.adobe.com/en_US/ActionScript/3.0_ProgrammingAS3/WS5b3ccc516d4fbf351e63e3d118a9b90204-7d01.html

Comment: also: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/370449/adobe-air-keyboard-hook

Comment: Android keyboard customization is fairly difficult simply because there are dozens and dozens of keyboards out there and almost every OEM uses their own customized keyboard. It is unlikely you will be able to accomplish what you want, at least in AIR.

Comment: so how about whatsapp when using any keyboard it shows the "Send" button, or skype  etc... so it is impossible then?

Comment: I'm talking about this:  http://developer.android.com/guide/topics/ui/controls/text.html

How to enable this using Flash and AIR?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

After reading a lot, and searching on Google, I came across the **StageText** option using AIR, it will handle the text and keyboard in a better way than using **textInput**.

Read about it here: http://blogs.adobe.com/cantrell/archives/2011/09/native-text-input-with-stagetext.html

Answer (score 1):

You need to add the following properties to your textinput:

```
returnKeyLabel="go" 
enter="validate(event)"
```

The ReturnKeyLabel has different options, but you need GO. When pressing the button 'GO' it triggers the event. GL

Comment: This is what I get when adding that property:
**ReferenceError: Error #1056: Cannot create property returnKeyLabel on fl.controls.TextInput.**