# capturing keyboard events in adobe air background

Tags: apache-flex, air, air-native-extension

I am struggling to find a way so that i can capture keyboard events in adone air even when application is in background mode and sitting in system tray on windows.

Basically i want to make it so that if a user presses a certain combination of keys then adobe air detects it and performs a task. This all happens when the air desktop application is in background and focus is not on air app.

I found extension to capture native mouse movements but was not able to find any extension for capturing keyboard evenets.

Please suggest.

Thanks

Answer (score 0):

As the answers to [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/370449/adobe-air-keyboard-hook) state, you'll need to write your own native extension (or external app, invoked with NativeProcess) to globally capture keyboard events.

Comment: I am not expert in writing native extensions myself , can you please point me to a ready to use native extension for keyboard ?

Comment: I don't know of any, sorry.

Comment: ok, do you know c/c++ ,if so,  can you please add function in native mouse extension for keydown event ?